# Dynamically Add Footer to ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, footer

I am trying to add a footer row of DropDownLists to my GridView control. The problem is that I do not know how many columns will be in my DataSource at design time, so I am trying to use the AutoGenerateColumns=true and not specify the column templates. Therefore the way I am adding the DropDownList controls to the footer is in code dynamically on the DataBound event of the GridView.

This works fine except that I would like to do something with the SelectedItem of each of the DropDownLists when the users clicks a button. These dynamically added controls no longer seem to exist on the post back of the user clicking the button, I believe the problem is because I am not specifying the runat="server" tag on the DropDownList controls.

Is there a different way I could be adding these drop downs to a FooterTemplate without specifying all of the columns so I can have access to their SelectedItems when the user clicks a button on the page?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to instantiate the controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're partially right -- the dynamically added controls don't exist anymore after the postback. They won't get re-added until the DataBound event is run. The problem is that Databinding events happen **after** control events, that is, **after** your button's Click event. So, at the point in the page lifecycle where the click event is handled, those controls haven't been recreated yet.

[Here's a related question which might have some useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113392/dynamically-added-controls-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 0):

you need to create an Addhandler:

```
dim dropdownlistname as new Dropdownlist
Addhandler dropdownlistname.selected_indexchanged,AddressOf dropdownlistname_SelectedIndexChanged
```

then you need to create a sub as follows:

```
Protected Sub dropdownlistname_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddldept.SelectedIndexChanged

'Insert Code here

End sub
```

So what this does is it creates an Event and declared an Address to go for that event. You should be able to write whatever code in this event.