# Dynamic text box vanishing if another button or link button clicked

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, html

the code written below displays the text box for a certain condition.But when i click another unrelated button or link it dissapears.i need it to stay visible when i do other activities on the webpage

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox new_textbox = new TextBox();

    if (DropDownList1.Text.Equals("OFF"))
    {
        new_textbox.ID = "txt" + 1;

        PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new_textbox);
        Label5.Visible = true;
        new_textbox.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {   
        Label5.Visible = false;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked on SO before:
[Dynamically added controls in Asp.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113392/dynamically-added-controls-in-asp-net)

You are only adding this control in a certain situation, specifically when `DropDownList1.Text.Equals("OFF")`. Could you instead have a static control that you just set visible in this case?

According to msdn's [Add Controls to an ASP.NET Web Page Programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1.aspx):

> Controls are typically added to the page during the page's
>   initialization stage. For details about page stages, see ASP.NET Page
>   Life Cycle Overview.

The quote links to [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

You have to be careful about adding controls dynamically, see this msdn page about [Dynamic Web Server Controls and View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbdfdyh7.aspx).