# How to access values from dynamically added user control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, viewstate

I want to get values from dynamically added user control

I'm trying but count comes as 0 so condition  failed

Code:

```
private const string VIEWSTATEKEY = "ContactCount";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Set the number of default controls
            ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] = ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] == null ? 1 : ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY];

            //Load the contact control based on Vewstate key
            LoadContactControls();
        }
    }


 private void LoadContactControls()
 {
    for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY].ToString()); i++)
    {
        rpt1.Controls.Add(LoadControl("AddVisaControl.ascx"));
    }
 }

 protected void addnewtext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY] = int.Parse(ViewState[VIEWSTATEKEY].ToString()) + 1;
     LoadContactControls();
 }
```

**EDIT**

Here is the problem count takes as 0 so condition failed loop comes out

```
private void saveData()
{
    foreach (var control in rpt1.Controls)
        {
            var usercontrol = control as VisaUserControl;

            string visaNumber = usercontrol.TextVisaNumber;
            string countryName = usercontrol.VisaCountry;
        }
    }
}

protected void Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    saveData();
}
```

.ascx.cs

```
    public string TextVisaNumber
    {
        get { return txtUser.Text; }
        set { txtUser.Text = value; }
    }

    public string VisaCountry
    {
        get { return dropCountry.SelectedValue; }
        set { dropCountry.SelectedValue = value; }
    }
```

.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AddVisaControl.ascx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="Pyramid.AddVisaControl" %>
<%@ Register assembly="BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" namespace="BasicFrame.WebControls" tagprefix="BDP" %>
<div id="divreg" runat="server">
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Visa Number:</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
<td> Country Name:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Type of Visa:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
<td> Type of Entry:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Expiry Date</td>
    <td><BDP:BasicDatePicker ID="basicdate" runat="server"></BDP:BasicDatePicker></td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [public property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15809041/accessing-values-of-dynamic-user-controls-in-asp-net) in your user control.
And access that property through the id of the user control.
See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/113392/dynamically-added-controls-in-asp-net) and Th[i](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14216030/maintain-the-state-of-dynamically-added-user-control-on-postback)s question.

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ offtopic: how old are you that after deleting your question I've suddenly got 2 downvotes on my answers? One very old but most upvoted and one accepted? Very mature behavior. Cheers...

Answer (score 0):

Always assign id to the controls you are adding its a good practice.

```
Control ctrl = Page.LoadControl("~/UserControls/ReportControl.ascx");
ctrl.ID = "UniqueID";
```

Also since you are adding controls dynamically you need to manage view state of the same, or add third party controls who do this part for you.